# Custom queries using arrays and implode function in php

Tags: php, mysql, implode

I am coding a game site. On this site, every question should be displayed to the user only once. Questions ID's are stored in a one field:

name of field in table: **hidden_questions**

hidden_questions values :**1,2,3,17**

I'm trying to get the IDs from the database and store them in an array using the implode function:

```
$q1= array($data['question_id']);
$q2= implode(',', $q1); // returns 1,2,3,4,5
```

And I want to display a non-repeat question using the following query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM question WHERE question_id!=('".$q2."') LIMIT 1";
```

This code does not work and questions with the ID stored in the **hidden_questions** field are displayed. please guide me.

Comment: You probably want to say `SELECT... WHERE... NOT IN()`

Comment: `!=('".$q2."')` should be `NOT IN ($q2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that someone already wrote a comment about the solution, but I still write it down for you.

You are on the right way and I understand what you want to do. But, MySQL does not have something like `!=` in this syntax.

Maybe you can try to use the [`NOT IN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM question WHERE question_id NOT IN (".$b.") LIMIT 1";
```

Also, why do you use the `LIMIT 1`? According to your explanation it looks like that you want to show multiple questions.

Disclaimer: I did not test the code, maybe you needto play some with the quotes. But this should be the solution